# Trouble with web service using Apache Axis2 and Tomcat version7

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, apache-axis, war

I developed a web service in eclipse 1 month back which is running fine. I generated war files and removed the  source code. Now I have to run the war files.

To run the war files I kept both my client and server war files in webapps folder and ran the startup batch file in bin folder.

Then I am using localhost+path on browser. I am able to see first page. when I am giving input and submitting I am not able to get results back

It is showing the following in command prompt:

**I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect**

Please help

Thanks

Comment: The real lesson is to save your source, preferably in a place you can get at.

Answer (score 0):

I some how doubt that the war which is having the server files(with implementation logic), is not getting deployed/ run correctly. Try starting the server and try to hit the wsdl url, which would be something like(http://localhost:/nameofservice.wsdl)